# Event propogation not working in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I made a custom `contextmenu` directive. And I am trying to log something when the `contextmenu` opens. However the same function runs 5 times, when its supposed to run once. I am trying to `e.stopPropagation()`; but the `CSS` doesn't apply from the first go, I have to click again, and then its working properly. What am I doing wrong?

Here's how my link function in the directive looks:

```
$ele.on('contextmenu', '*', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $scope.$apply(function () {

        $scope.visible = true;
        $('.parented').css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY, position: 'absolute'}).show();
        var ele = e.target;

        $scope.souls = {
            elementType: ele.nodeName,
            content: ele.innerText,
            id: ele.id,
            class: ele.className
        }

        console.log($scope.souls)
    })
});
```

And the `HTML`

```
<div prevent visible="isVisible" ravi="someData" sound="sound(souls)" souls="souls">

    <p class="haseebtesting">abc</p>
    <table class="datatable">
        <tr ng-repeat="t in templateData">
            <td class="haseebtesting" ng-click="current.selected = t; confusedFunction(t)" id="{{'test ' + $index}}">{{t.templateName}}</td>
            <td>{{t.templatePath}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    {{souls}} <br /><br />

    <div ng-if="isVisible" class="parented">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical notclick" role="group" aria-label="Vertical button group">
            <form class="haseebform">
                <input type="text" ng-model="souls.entername" placeholder="Enter name"> <br>
                <input type="text" ng-model="souls.entercomment" placeholder="Enter comment">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addT(souls)" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Working link here: https://aijazkhan81.github.io/contextmenu/

Comment: can you provide a fiddle to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: @Gonzalo.- Here's the link on JSbin http://jsbin.com/voduvivuda/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: how can I reproduce the problem ? I don't completely understand the fiddle. I don't see any console.log error

Comment: @Gonzalo.- I couldn't get it to work there. I made a repo on github, and added it to gh-pages as well.
https://github.com/aijazkhan81/contextmenu/tree/gh-pages